# Apps running without any CSS and jQuery Mobile format in Ripple emulator in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, cross-platform, visual-studio-2015, ripple

When I run my app with ripple emulator in Visual Studio 2015, I see it without any css format like pic(1). But when I open normaly **index.html** in browser, It appear correctly like pic(2).

Pic(1): My app in Ripple emulator

[image]

pic(2): My app in currect view

[image]

I'm beginner in Cross Platform programming.

- What's the problem?
- what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser(ripple emulator) blocks the ActiveX components. Is your view in the same browser as the emulator?

Comment: Tnx for your answer but I checked that,the browser ActiveX is allowing to run.Also I run it in the same browser as the emulator